# Hide/Show UI elements by MouseOut/MouseOver client handlers

Tags: event-handling, listbox, google-apps-script, mouseout

The goal is to mutually replace two elements with each-other by MouseOut/MouseOver events.  Specifically the elements are a label and a listbox. There are some UI arrangement in which the implementation works acceptably in Chrome, however it always fails in IE(9). The problem occurs during a selection from the listbox as per browsers ignor the dropped down area as part of the listbox, it triggers the mouseOut handler and hides the listbox.

**Is there any solution forcing browsers to consider the listbox together with its dropped down area?**

```
app.createListBox() .setId('listBox');
app.createLabel('Item1') .setId('label')
    .addMouseOverHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                         .forEventSource().setVisible(false)
                         .forTargets(app.getElementById('listBox')).setVisible(true));
app.getElementById('listBox')
    .addItem('Item1')
    .addItem('Item2')
    .setVisible(false)
    .addMouseOutHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                        .forEventSource().setVisible(false)
                        .forTargets(app.getElementById('label')).setVisible(true));
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a possible workaround using a server handler to hide the listBox.  From my tests it behaves quite similarly (if not better ) - you can [test it here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyxgXz7E0A516DkS3n2jPrdqt6Re7RTx2wOzu2fiLBuucN8M2U/exec)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setStyleAttribute('padding','100px');
  var p = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var serverHandler = app.createServerHandler('handler').addCallbackElement(p)
  var listBox = app.createListBox() .setId('listBox').setName('listBox').addChangeHandler(serverHandler);  
  var label = app.createLabel('Item1').setId('label')
    .addMouseOverHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                         .forEventSource().setVisible(false)
                         .forTargets(listBox).setVisible(true));

  listBox.addItem('Item1').addItem('Item2').addItem('Item3').addItem('Item4')         
              .setVisible(false)

  p.add(listBox).add(label)
  app.add(p)
  return app                       
}

function handler(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var listBox = app.getElementById('listBox')
  var label = app.getElementById('label')
  listBox.setVisible(false)
  label.setVisible(true).setText(e.parameter.listBox)
  return app
}
```

Comment: I came up with the same [solution](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/home/dev-test-listbox-label).

Comment: I just updated the code, I forgot some details to make it work... (handler ! ;-) @Jacobvdb - I guess it's indeed the best way to go ;-)

Comment: @Jacobvdb - for some reason I can't make your example work... could you have a look ? your code seems ok but the listBox stays visible...

Comment: Hey @serge insas just tried again and it seems to work although I noticed the response time being long.

Comment: strange, I copied/pasted your code in my app and it didn't work  either... can't find any real difference between your code and mine though... I just don't understand. if it works for you and everybody else that's ok, we're not going to spend the night on this :-)

Comment: Just tested in Chrome and it worked... do not know what is happening :-) maybe we just found a friday afternoon bug...haha

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, there are some problems with this solution:
listbox does not disappear by mouseOut event - which is one of the main goal, yes it could be sorted out with mouseOut condition instead the Change but that wold lead to the original problem flavoured with speed issue.
listbox does not disappear by leaving the listbox's item selection area - I haven't directly specified this requirement earlier.

Comment: The reason of all of this is to making large density information digesting easier. That means that the appereance of the listboxes is required only for during the selection as the appereance of the listbox unnecessarily increasing the density of the visual information. Your solution answered my question anyway as probably there is no solution for forcing browsers to consider listbox TOGETHER its dropped down area for event handling. I've just figured out a substitution as setting listbox's background and border colours to Transparent...
Thanks again, have a nice weekend